# bash script find line and modify next line

Tags: bash, scripting

I have a bash script that is modifying a file.
I have a sed that will go and find a line, and replace it with another argument:

```
sed -i 's@.leaflet-right {@/.leaflet-left {@g' "$<Path_to_my_file...>"
```

However I would like instead to find the line containing `.leaflet-right {` and then modify the next line from `right: 0;` to `left: 0;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#% cat tester
blah
blah
.leaflet-right {
right: 0; CHANGE
right  LEAVE
blah
blah
```

and then

```
 sed  '/.leaflet-right/{n;s/right/left/;}' < tester
```

gives

```
blah
blah
.leaflet-right {
left: 0; CHANGE
right  LEAVE
blah
blah
```

Comment: um, ok, I was doing all this:
        val1=`awk '/.leaflet-right {/ {print NR}' "$<path to file>"`
        editline1=$(expr $val1 + 1)
        appendval1="        left: 0;"
        sed -i "${editline1}s/\$/${appenval1}/" "$<path to file>"

but your solution is far better, thx!!

Answer (score 1):

With awk, you can use number of line like this:

This will print line number of line in which something happens (in the example, it contains text `something`)

```
awk '/something/ {print NR}'
```

This will print second field from previous line

```
awk -v v1=2 {if (FNR==v1-1) print $2}'
```

You can maybe make a combination of sed and awk for the final result.